# How to get all tags collections in woocommerce?

Tags: tags

I need to display all tag names in front end,I have tried

`$terms=get_terms('product_tag');`

But it returns null.

Can anyone please help me How to get it?

Comment: Do you have product tags (not regular tags) set, and are they actually attached to products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the array and create a separate array to check in_array because get_terms return object with in array.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
$term_array = array();
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_array[] = $term->name;
    }
}
```

[solution from stackoverflow click for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904758/woocommerce-get-product-tags-in-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the [`wc_get_product_tag_list()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-product-functions.php#L1129) function to get a list of the product's tags. It supports providing a separator along with before and after elements.

**Example**

```
<?php
    global $product;
?>
    <div class="product-tags">
        <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If get_terms() return error, you can try this:

```
function get_all_woo_tags(){
    $term_array = array();
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'               => 'product_tag',
        'orderby'                => 'name',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'             => false,
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
    foreach($the_query->get_terms() as $term){ 
        $term_array[] = $term->name;
    }
    return $term_array;
}
```